# seeing the latest block while running a node

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, fast-sync, full-node

prysm has no option of snap or full sync as far as I know but geth I snap synced then at 99% switched to full sync for command line params...  sync is sitting like 99.998% does it ever fully sync where you see the latest block? im like 200 blocks off or so do you have to be a trusted node or running for a while to get more recent updates? does it depend on the propagation path through the network?

Comment: thanks for the help!!!!